# Difference between bool and while (true) in C

Tags: c, while-loop, infinite-loop

I just came to know about `bool`. It seems that both `bool` and `while (true)` or `while (1)` are the same endless function. Does `bool` have any advantages over `while (true)` or `while (1)`?. I can't see any difference.

bool:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(void) 
{
    bool keep_going = true;  // Could also be `bool keep_going = 1;`
    while(keep_going) 
    {
        printf("This will run as long as keep_going is true.\n");
        // keep_going = false;    
        // Could also be `keep_going = 0;`
    }

    printf("Stopping!\n");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While(true) is an infinite loop. Boolean is a data type with true and false values. Bool is used in case if you want to change to false at any stage. So you can change the value of bool inside for loop to stop loop.

Comment: Also using `while(keep_going)` and then setting `keep_going` to false would let the current loop iteration finish before breaking the loop.  With `while(1)` and a `break` statement, the loop is broken immediately, possibly mid-loop.

Answer (score 4):

C evaluates all numbers that are [non-zero as `true`](https://www.le.ac.uk/users/rjm1/cotter/page_37.htm) whereas zero is regarded as `false`. So `while(true)` and `while(1)` are exactly the same.